# Grant access to a specific group in Azure AD for an application is not working

Tags: angular, azure, azure-ad-msal, passport-azure-ad

I'm trying to create an Angular website and I'm using MSAL for authentication and passport-azure-ad in nodejs. While registering the Angular app in Azure AD, I have created a group containing 1 user only and I added this group to the registered Angular application to grant access to this group, only but everyone in same tenant can login and access even protected routes.

Here is my nodejs code so I think this code is enough to validate the token sent from Angular:

```
// authRouter.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var tokenValidationCache = new Map();
const azureConfig=require('../azure.conf.json')
const passport = require('passport');
const BearerStrategy = require('passport-azure-ad').BearerStrategy;

var languageController = require('../controllers/qnalanguage.controller');

const options = {

    identityMetadata: `https://${azureConfig.metadata.authority}/${azureConfig.credentials.tenantID}/${azureConfig.metadata.version}/${azureConfig.metadata.discovery}`,
    issuer: null,
    validateIssuer: azureConfig.settings.validateIssuer,
    clientID: azureConfig.credentials.clientID,
    audience: azureConfig.credentials.audience,
    passReqToCallback: azureConfig.settings.passReqToCallback,
    loggingLevel: azureConfig.settings.loggingLevel,
    scope: azureConfig.resource.scope,
    loggingNoPII: false,
    clockSkew: 300
};

const bearerStrategy = new BearerStrategy(options, (token, done) => {
    const roles = token.roles || [];
    const user = {};
    return done(null, user, token);
});

passport.use(bearerStrategy);
router.use(passport.initialize());
router.use(passport.authenticate('oauth-bearer', { session: false }), (req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.authInfo = req.authInfo;
    return next();
});
router.get('/source', languageController.getQnAHtml);
router.post('/knowledgebase', languageController.chatbotqaAdd);
router.delete('/knowledgebase/:id', languageController.chatbotqaDelete);
router.post('/knowledgebase/deploy', languageController.chatbotqaUpdateSource);
router.post('/init', languageController.initMongoDbQNA);
router.put('/knowledgebase',languageController.chatbotqaUpdate)
router.get('/knowledgebase', languageController.getQNA);
router.get('/protected',(req, res) => {
    res.send({'res':'Hello! This resource is protected.'})
}
)
module.exports = router;
```

And here is my function that fetching the posts from my nodejs server

```
fetchPosts() {
    let headers= new HttpHeaders()
    headers=headers.set('authorization','')
    this.http.get(`${this.baseurl}/api/v1/auth/knowledgebase`)
    .subscribe((posts:any)=>{console.log(posts)
    this.posts=posts})
}
```

```
export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {

  const protectedResourceMap = new Map<string, Array<string>>();

  protectedResourceMap.set('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me',

 [...environment.apiConfig.scopes]);

  protectedResourceMap.set('http://www.localhost:8000/*',[...environment.apiConfig.scopes])


  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    protectedResourceMap
  };
}
```

here is my node config.json

```
    {
    "credentials": {
      "tenantID": "tenantid",
      "clientID": "client id",
      "audience": "api://audience"
    },
    "resource": {
      "scope": ["general"]
    },
    "metadata": {
      "authority": "sts.windows.net",
      "discovery": ".well-known/openid-configuration",
      "version": "v2.0"
    },
    "settings": {
      "validateIssuer": false,
      "passReqToCallback": false,
      "loggingLevel": "info"
    }
  }
```

[image: here is my group that i assigned to angular app]

What I want to do is to restrict the access to my app to that group only. I already followed this tutorial but it didn't work for me.

https://fluentjs.medium.com/angular-spa-and-node-js-api-with-azure-ad-for-authentication-in-2021-b2974666c2eb

Comment: Enable Assignment required option in Enterprise application like [**this**](https://i.imgur.com/VW87psj.png) and check

Comment: thx now it's working ,but i have another question in nodejs api should i set "validateIssuer" to true or false ? right now is set to false, also do i have to assign the group to my nodejs registered app ?

Comment: You can set validateIssuer based on your requirement and assign group to the angulardemo Enterprise application only

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62829915/azure-ad-token-validation-why-validate-issuer

Comment: when i set validateIssuer to true i get this "authentication failed due to: jwt issuer is invalid"

Comment: what value you get in issuer?

Comment: in req.authInfo in iss i get https://sts.windows.net/mytenantid

Comment: ok thx , i wil post new question

Comment: i posted a new question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Note** that: To Grant access to a specific group in Azure AD for an application, you need to enable Assignment required option in Enterprise application and add group in the Users and groups tab.

***Go to Enterprise application -> Properties -> Assignment required -> YES***

[image]

Now add the group in the Users and groups tab:

[image]

Now only the users in the group will be able to access the application.